# How to calculate variable importance for different models? is varImp() the solution?

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret

I'm using caret's train() function for a binary classification outcome with different models (nb, knn, lda, qda, glm, rpart, rf).

I'm using varImp() and plots to determine the importance of every feature, but I've heard that this is not recommended.

Any tips or suggestions?

Comment: (1) Various, & rather disparate, metrics can answer to the name of variable importance - so I think you need to explain what you want to get from "variable importance" in your particular application. (2) If it matters at all to be able to compare the "importance" of a predictor across different models, then you need to use the same metric across different models (`varImp`'s default choice may differ across them).

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate response!

Comment: In answer to (1) The two predictors I'm using have the same characteristics; they are both numerical estimates that express something similar, I'd like to determine which one is more important to the each model. 
(2) Curiously when I use varImp(), but scaled, the result is always the same across all the models: 100 for one predictor and 0 for the other